# Mule - when to use messaging patterns?

Tags: mule, messaging

Excuse what might be a vague question, i'll try and detail as much as I can.

I have to build an app in Mule that copies files from an amazon s3 bucket to a file system and send some notifications along the way. It also has to move the files to a processing s3  bucket before moving them to my filesystem.

So in order:

Get files from s3 bucket
Move to processing s3 bucket
Do Some validation
Write to file system
Any errors write them to error bucket

This is quite simple and I can do this in Mule quite simply using flows/sub-flows in a procedural way.

But should I really be doing this using Messaging patterns as Mule is an 'ESB'?
Should I be splitting these process up via vm/jms queues? Or is just using sub flows in a procedural way ok?

What is the best practice of when to use queues instead of just procedural sub flows?

Answer (score 0):

Messaging is so sophisticated in mule and even if you use flow/subflows internally in clustering and load balancing,  mule uses the vm queues to communicate between the flows/subflows do them.

There is no necessary to use messaging patterns unless your flow is too complex